Ubuntu 24.04 softraid (md) install and boot
Trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 server using 2 NVMe in software raid (using TUI installation)
i need to set them in mirror and install + boot Ubuntu 24 from them.
when creating a raid (md) or LVM for both of disks (raid created automatically) i cannot select boot disk/partition, it's just grey in menus.
tried to do silent installation using autoinstall, cloud-init user-data yaml
installation is failing on "autoinstall did not create needed bootloader partition"
any ideas?

We also had this issue and we also found somewhere the solution. But I will repeat the process here, so anybody can find and apply:

Select the first drive you want as boot-partition and select as boot partition
Select the second drive and select as another boot partition
Create for drive one and two another partition with the remaining space and leave it unformatted
Now you can create the md raid for the remaining partitions.

As result, your lsblk would look like the following:
nvme6n1     259:0    0   1.9T  0 disk
├─nvme6n1p1 259:2    0     1G  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme6n1p2 259:3    0   1.9T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0   1.9T  0 raid1 /
nvme7n1     259:1    0   1.9T  0 disk
├─nvme7n1p1 259:4    0     1G  0 part
└─nvme7n1p2 259:5    0   1.9T  0 part
  └─md0       9:0    0   1.9T  0 raid1 /

As you can see, only one partition is mounted as boot.
